# Read information from embed message Discord.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG6LG.jpg)
I want my keytritz bot to react to an embed when the title is naruto / Naruto but in the first one I got an error (# 1) but it did not affect the functionality but in the second embed (#2) I got an error that the keytritz bot did not react and did not commented
, I leave a link where is the code of both bots, the mudae bot is not mine.
https://mega.nz/folder/IIUHEabJ#IIaRNcMgUS2gC-d_lZXQZw
https://top.gg/bot/432610292342587392

CODE Keytritz:

```
      for(var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
        message.channel.send(message.content.embeds);
          if(message.embeds[i].title.includes("naruto")){
              message.react(" ")
              message.channel.send("Detected");
              break;
          }
      }
```

Embed lxXxandresxXxl

```
  if(message.content.startsWith(prefix+"r")) {
    message.channel.send({ embed: {
      color: 3447003,
      author: {
        name: client.user.username,
        icon_url: client.user.displayAvatarURL()
      },
      title: "This is an naruto embed",
      url: "http://google.com",
      description: "This is a test embed to showcase what they look like and what they can do.",
      fields: [{
        name: "Fields",
        value: "They can have different fields with small headlines."
      },
      {
        name: "Masked links",
        value: "You can put [masked links](http://google.com) inside of rich embeds."
      },
      {
        name: "Markdown",
        value: "You can put all the *usual* **__Markdown__** inside of them."
      }
      ],
      timestamp: new Date(),
      footer: {
        icon_url: client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
        text: "© Example"
      }
    }
  });
  }
```

Error 1#

```
(node:1744) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message
        at RequestHandler.execute (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:154:13)
        at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:88:5)
        at async RequestHandler.push (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    (node:1744) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
    (node:1744) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Error 2#

```
if(message.embeds[i].title.includes("naruto")){
                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null
at Client.<anonymous> (/app/server.js:90:36)
    at Client.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:196:13)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/rbd/pnpm-volume/8bd4e7c9-1711-40fc-be45-7d082848ec2a/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/discord.js/12.5.3/node_modules/discord.js/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:983:20)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I evaluate some code to tries to basically replicated what you do. and i come up with this code. Might help you a little bit, and also i **tried this with my other test bot** and i also found out if you sends a link for example https://google.com it will have an embed but on discord it isnt meaning it just read actual embed like from other bot or smth, anyway here what i got so far.
**Discord.js V13**

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => {
```

```js
    if(message.embeds.length >= 0) 
    // Check if the Message has embed or not
    {
      let embed = message.embeds
      // console.log(embed) just a console.log

      for(let i = 0; i < embed.length; i++)
      // Loop it since in v13 you can send multiple embed in single message
      {
        
        if(embed[i].title === null) return;
        // check each embed if it has title or not, if it doesnt then do nothing

        if(embed[i].title.toLowerCase().includes('hi'))
        // check each embed if it includes word 'hi' or not
        {
          message.react('')
          message.react('')
        }
      }
    }
```

```js
})
```

- **P.S.** This code will read another bot message
- **P.S.S** If someone has a better way explained the code or wants to make changes, feel free to edit it